# Restore existing .bak file using bak module in Python

Tags: python, sql, backup, restore

I am trying to restore a .bak SQL server backup file in Python using the bak module. How do I restore a .bak file already in my folder to .mdb file using item.restore()? I am open to suggestions to other Python modules or R packages that can accomplish the same task.

Comment: you can just restore it by renaming the `.bak` file by hand (without python) into `.mdb`

Comment: I am using MacOS and I have tried changing the extension but that could not restore the database, maybe I am missing something. When I change the extension, and try the read it , all I get is loads of symbols with some letters in it.